# Is there node module to detect already running files?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a long running script run as a cron job that runs every 15 minutes. The problem is that if the scripts runs more then 15 minutes there could possibly be another instance of the script running at the same time. This cannot happen. Is there a node module that can be loaded in a script that can detect if the script its in is already running as a process and not allow starting of the script upon detecting already running instance?

I made some code that does this utilizing the ps aux command in php and it works well. Just wondering if there is a node module that does this?

Comment: A common way to solve this in software (not just Node.js) is to create a "lock file". When the script starts, it makes sure the file doesn't exist; if that check passes, it creates the file and runs. It deletes the file when it finishes. If the file does exist, the script is already running, so the second instance stops itself. The file doesn't need to contain anything in particular.

Comment: So, it's off-topic here on stack overflow to ask for 3rd party modules that already do this.  You can ask how one would code this yourself in node.js or ask for help with the code you're already trying to write yourself.  And, you could certainly use the node child_process module to use the same `ps aux` method you were using in PHP.